# Excel non-continuous data points (Power Pivot)

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot, excel-charts

I have a pivot table with some data points like this: [image]

To display a line graph i need y-values for every point, so i formatted the table to insert 0 in every cell with no value, which gives me this: 
[image]

What i need is a way for the pivot table to just use the most recent y-value when ever it's missing a value. I've simulated this manually like this: [image]

Is there a way to do this with pivot tables?

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing fancy, but I believe a calculated column is a good solution for this. Here's one example:

[image]